# Insert something “Before the end of document”

Tags: macros, environments

I insert the name and licence with the command `\nameofcompany` at the end of my document like this:

```
\nameofcompany
\end{document}
```

Now, I want to generalize it to some documents, for that I found `\AtEndDocument{\nameofcompany}` but it doesn't have exactly the same result than `\nameofcompany  \end{document}`. It seems that with `\AtEndDocument`, the command is only executed after `\end{document}`, while I want it to be executed before.

I also try to redefine the `document` environment like this

```
\renewenvironment{document}%
  {\begin{document}}
  {%
  \nameofcompany
%
  \end{document}%
  }
```

but it doesn't work either.

Is there a command like `\beforTheEndDocument`?

Comment: What is the problem? The output for your personal command is not shown? Please, post a minimal example with the problem.

Comment: Please, correct those lot of typos on your post.

Comment: Insert `\AtEndDocument{}` on preamble not on the body.

Comment: @Sigur I've done some of them. `:)`

Comment: Sigur, I’ll fix it. Yes, i put `\AtEndDocument{}` on the preamble. I prepare the minimal example.

Comment: @fauve, be careful to not remove the edition done by Svend.

Comment: Probably a bad idea in many ways, but what about `\usepackage{etoolbox}` and then `\preto\enddocument{\nameofcompany\par}`?

Comment: Another, less problematic idea using 'etoolbox' is something like '\AtEndEnvironment{document}{\nameofcompany\par}' (where the '\par' may or may not be appropriate). No idea why this would work when '\AtEndDocument' fails, but it happened to me once.

Answer (score 18):

```
\AtEndDocument{<stuff>}
```

is a shorthand equivalent to

```
<stuff>
\end{document}
```

Why? Look at the definition of `\enddocument` (from [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx)):

```
\def\enddocument{%
   \let\AtEndDocument\@firstofone
   \@enddocumenthook
   \@checkend{document}%
   \clearpage
   \begingroup
     \if@filesw
       \immediate\closeout\@mainaux
       \let\@setckpt\@gobbletwo
       \let\@newl@bel\@testdef
       \@tempswafalse
       \makeatletter \@@input\jobname.aux
     \fi
     \@dofilelist
     \ifdim \font@submax >\fontsubfuzz\relax
       \@font@warning{Size substitutions with differences\MessageBreak
                  up to \font@submax\space have occurred.\@gobbletwo}%
     \fi
     \@defaultsubs
     \@refundefined
     \if@filesw
       \ifx \@multiplelabels \relax
         \if@tempswa
           \@latex@warning@no@line{Label(s) may have changed.
               Rerun to get cross-references right}%
         \fi
       \else
         \@multiplelabels
       \fi
     \fi
   \endgroup
   \deadcycles\z@\@@end}
```

`\@enddocumenthook` is the hook that is updated by `\AtEndDocument`:

```
\def\AtEndDocument{\g@addto@macro\@enddocumenthook}
```

---

You may consider alternative end-of-document hooks by looking into the [`atveryend` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/atveryend). It provides the following hooks, all of which are executed *after* the `\AtEndDocument` hook, except the first:

> `BeforeClearDocument{<code>}`
>
> The code is called before the final `\clearpage` in `\enddocument`. However it is
>   unknown, whether the last page is already shipped out or if this will be triggered
>   by the final `\clearpage`.
>
> `\AfterLastShipout{<code>}`
>
> The code is called after the final `\clearpage` of `\enddocument` before the main
>   `.aux` file is closed. This is the right place to remember the last page in the `.aux`
>   file, for instance.
>
> `\AtVeryEndDocument{<code>}`
>
> The code is called after the `.aux` file is closed and read in again. It is the place
>   for final checks, rerun hints, final messages.
>
> `\AtEndAfterFileList{<code>}`
>
> After the `.aux` file closing and reading LaTeX prints the file list if requested by
>   `\listfiles`. Then this hook is executed.
>
> `\AtVeryVeryEnd{<code>}`
>
> This code is called right before the final `\@@end`.

Refer to the definition of `\enddocument` in order to see an approximate location where the above hooks are placed.