# Trigger the final bibliography from the beginning

Tags: formatting, templates

I'd like to add **at the top** of a .tex file a line to enable a command placed **at the bottom** of it (for instance, `\printbibliography`)

Why ? Firstly, in order to make easily disable this command in a very long .tex file. Even better, in order to externalise this line in a template input file, called at the beginning of the compiling process.

I've already tried to redefine the command `\end{document}` to adding `\printbibliography` before, like that :

```
\newcommand{\end{document}}[1]{\printbibliography \end{document}}}
```

But it doesn't work (it would have been too simple).

Here is an MWE :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Bob1996,
  title = {A {{Very Nice Title}}},
  volume = {10},
  number = {2},
  journaltitle = {Annual Review of Nothing},
  date = {1996},
  author = {Bob, Bob}
}
@article{John1996,
  title = {A {{Nice Title}}},
  volume = {10},
  issue = {2-3},
  journaltitle = {Annual Review of Something},
  date = {1996},
  author = {John, John}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{biblatex}    
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib} 

% What I tried :
% \newcommand{\end{document}}[1]{\printbibliography \end{document}}}

\begin{document}

... A long long long text...

% Here is the command I need to remove, without removing 
% the bibliography itself in the output file :
% \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224934/insert-something-before-the-end-of-document work?

Comment: It works perfectly ! It was so simple... Thank you ! :-)